# Select special part of a uri, which consist of no special characters

Tags: c#

I have such a URLs `www.example.com/e24/konfigurace-obchodnich-partneru/+bb.ddd@ttt.com`. I am looking for a function, which extracts segments of this uri, but not the segment, which consist of email address. Something like this:

- www.example.com
- e24
- konfigurace-obchodnich-partneru

and not `+bb.ddd@ttt.com`. I know I can use array an Regular expressions, but I am looking for a special function in C#. I have found [uri class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx). But it doesn't help me. How do you mean?

Comment: I would definitely go with regex to be honest.

Comment: *"I have founded uri class. But it doesn't help me. How do you mean?"* What do **you** mean? the Uri-class seems like a perfect fit and even a simple `Split("/")` would work on this example. Determining if the part is an email address is a completely different matter altogether.

Comment: This class has no function to filter @ for example

Comment: @Kaja If you are looking for a function that parses,splits **and** filters a Uri, you won't find one. Why not make it a two step process? (Determine parts, remove email addresses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's no special meaning in the URI format for the email-style segment you're looking for, you won't find a built-in function for this specific part. URIs don't care about the contents of their path segment, only their validity.

The simplest way to do it is to use the `Uri` class, as you found, extract the path segments using the `Segments` property, and check each segment if it matches the email format (which is a whole 'nother kettle of fish).

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/e24/konfigurace-obchodnich-partneru/+bb.ddd@ttt.com");
foreach (var segment in uri.Segments.Where(seg => !seg.Contains("@")))
{
    Console.WriteLine(segment);
}
```